# JS Append Row in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden field with some values, I have to append these values in HTML table.The number of columns in table is fixed.
I have appended successfully,but after first row,it should append data in new row,instead it is appending in the same row.
This is how I am doing

```
$("#btntbl").click(function () {
                debugger
                var tabl = $("#testTable");
                var vals = $("#txthidden").val();
                for (var i = 0; i < vals.split(";").length; i++) {                       
                        for (var j = 0; j < vals.split(";")[i].split(",").length; j++) {
                        tabl.append("<td>" + vals.split(";")[i].split(",")[j] + "</td>");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Also note that some users dont have value of disabled column
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wz7h68q4/9/)
How can I add new row each time clicking the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split twice and create `tr` for each row:

```js
$("#btntbl").click(function () {

  var tabl = $("#testTable"),
      vals = $("#txthidden").val(),
      rows = vals.split(';'),
      columns, i;

  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    columns = rows[i].split(',');
    tabl.append(
      '<tr>' + 
          '<td>' + columns[0] + '</td>' + 
          '<td>' + columns[1] + '</td>' + 
          '<td>' + (columns[2] || '') + '</td>' + 
      '</tr>'
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btntbl" value="Export to table">
<input type="hidden" value="User1,pwd1;User2,pwd2,disabled;User3,pwd3,disabled;User4,pwd4" id="txthidden" />
<table id="testTable" border="2">
    <thead valign="top">
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Disabled</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: @ dsfq : Hi dont you think for templating  ,we should use Angular js or Mustache , Handle bars instead of Speghetti jQuery code ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com For more complex applications for sure. But in this case I' don't know OP's set up, so I can't introduce one more dependency without real need. For this simple example I would go with string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Just change target by adding a row

Change

```
var tabl = $("#testTable");
```

To

```
var tabl = $('<tr>');
$("#testTable").append( tab1);
```

Answer (score 1):

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wz7h68q4/17/)***

```
$("#btntbl").click(function () {                  
    var parts = $("#txthidden").val().split(";"), i=0;
    for (;i<parts.length;) {
        var j=0, tr="<tr>", subParts=parts[i++].split(",");          
        for (;j<3;)  tr += "<td>" + (subParts[j++]||"") +"</td>"; // concatenate
        $("#testTable").append( tr +"</tr>" );                    // Append once
    }
});
```

Comment: its working but its appending User1, Pwd1 then User2,pwd2 in same row, I need User1,PWd1 in first row,then User2,Pwd2 in second row

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi edited. (moved `"<tr>"` stuff inside the for loop)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it

```
var convertToTable = function (val) {
   val = val.split(';');
   val = val.map(function (v) {
      v = v.split(',');
      if (v.length === 2) v[v.length] = 'NA';
      return '<td>' + v.join('</td><td>') + '</td>';
   });
   val = '<tr>' + val.join('</tr><tr>') + '</tr>';
   return val;
}
```

and then

```
tabl.html(convertToTable(vals));
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wz7h68q4/13/)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about TD tag, just use open tag before TD and close it in the end